# How to add string "\n" literally at the end of each line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Here is a string `str`:

```
str = "line1
       line2
       line3"
```

We would like to add string "\n" to the end of each line:

```
str = "line1 \n
       line2 \n
       line3 \n"
```

A method is defined:

```
   def mod_line(str)
     s = ""
     str.each_line do |l|
       s += l + '\\n'
     end
   end
```

The problem is that '\n' is a line feed and was not added to the end of the `str` even with escape `\`. What's the right way to add '\n' literally to each line?

Comment: There must be \n at the end of each line already if `each_line` works. But you should show us what you got in any case.

Comment: Need '\n' literally at the end. Has nothing to do with ruby's line feed.

Comment: `7urkm3n`, how `#{ s+= "#{l} \n"}` fit into the method?

Comment: @user938363 sorry it should be like this `s+= "#{l} \n"`

Comment: Your description is wrong. When you write `"... \n ..."`, the relevant part means the endline character `"\n"`. You need to write it `"... \\n ..."`. But why are you using such confusing string here to ask a question? Don't you think your question will be clearer if you used some other string?

Comment: `7urkm3n`, the result does not show \n at the end of the line.

Comment: `sawa`, just need the string fed into a method (don't ask me why \n has to be at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub)/[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) plus a very simple [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) can be used to achieve that:

```
str = "line1
       line2
       line3"
str.gsub!(/$/, ' \n')
puts str
```

Output:

```
line1 \n
       line2 \n
       line3 \n
```

Comment: What is `%(str = "#{str}")` for? Can't it be just `str`? Also, your output seems wrong. Shouldn't you have `\\n`s?

Answer (score 3):

The platform-independent solution:

```
str.gsub(/\R/) {  " \\n#{$~}" }
```

It will search for line-feeds/carriage-returns and replace them with themselves, prepended by `\n`.

Comment: I didn't know about `/R`.

Comment: @sawa Maybe it’s not worth it. `\R` is flaky. In fact, it’s extrapolated to a combination of joined regular expressions, that prevents it from e.g. using outside of regexp.

Comment: Actually got 2 `\n` One seems to be line feed.

Comment: You got exactly what you asked for. The glitches you might see are the glitches with output.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`\n` needs to be interpreted as a special character. You need to put it in double quotes.</strike>

```
"\n"
```

Your attempt:

```
'\\n'
```

only escapes the backslash, which is actually redundant. With or without escaping on the backslash, it gives you a backslash followed by the letter `n`.

Also, your method `mod_line` returns the result of `str.each_line`, which is the original string `str`. You need to return the modified string `s`:

```
def mod_line(str)
  ...
  s
end
```

<strike>And by the way, be aware that each line of the original string already has `"\n"` at the end of each line, so you are adding the second `"\n"` to each line (making it two lines).</strike>

Comment: @cremno Thanks. The question was misleading on that, since it wrote "\n" in double quotes (without code formatting).

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I got to it.

```
def mod_line(str)
         s = ""
     str.each_line do |l|
           s += l
     end
         p s
   end
```

Using p instead of puts leaves the \n on the end of each line.

Comment: Using both `p` and `puts` has nothing to do with the string itself; is changes the way how the string is printed out.

Comment: @mudasobwa But `p` returns the receiver, unlike `puts`.

Comment: @sawa so what? the code above is an [“ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of `itself`”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) :)